# Jquery On element load from external script

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I have external script that adds some element to my page. This script loads async after document.ready:

```
<script src="http://any.com/script.js"></script>
```

This script contains next:

```
$.ajax({
       url: '/anyScript',
       complete: function(){
          alert('yo'); // FIRED
          $('body').append('<div id="xxx" />'); // FIRED
       }
   });
```

I need to wait until this element will appear and add some styles to it

```
$(function(){

    $('body').on('load','#xxx', function(){
        $(this).css({
            background:'red',
            width: 100,
            height: $('#first_el').height()
        });
    });
});
```

This doesn't fire. What to do?

UPDATED: http://jsfiddle.net/81ucdoLo/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is based on the assumption that you don't have any control over the external script. So the proposed solution is to use an interval based solution to check whether the target element is loaded if so style it and then stop the interval.

In that case, try use $.getScript() to load the script like

```
jQuery.getScript('http://any.com/script.js', function () {
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        var $el = $('#xxx');
        if ($el.length) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            $el.css({
                background: 'red',
                width: 100,
                height: $('#first_el').height()
            });
        }
    }, 500);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/81ucdoLo/4/)

Comment: Yes, I think the only one way to make interval. This is work for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `ajaxComplete` as shown :

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $('#xxx').css({
    background:'red',
    width: 100,
    height: $('#first_el').height()
 });
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/81ucdoLo/5/)

Comment: Good solution. But it doesn't help me. It can be not ajax request, and xmlHttprequest or timeout or I can have a lot of different ajax requests. So I only need to listen when element will appear

Comment: @SergeyKudryashov..okk but as per your question and fiddle where you are showing just ajax request .. i think this is the most compact and useful answer..i think you should update your question and specify completely what else do you want.

Answer (score 0):

This should wait for the element to be ready:

```
$(function(){
  $("#xxx").css('top','123px');
  //OR
  $("#xxx").addClass('topMargin');
});
```

Comment: Updated. The value is calculated by js. And script loads after document is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Do somthing like this, call your js function using window.onload, it will execute doSomthing function after your page load.

```
window.onload = function() {doSomthing();}

function doSomthing()
{
   $("#xxx").css('top','123px');

}
```

Or add timeout,

```
setTimeout(doSomthing,1000);
```

this will delay the call process, and will call after specified time.

What if you try this : 
[JSFiddle Demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/81ucdoLo/2/)

I updated your demo.